# Creating SPA tic-tac-toe game with arrays and basic js knowledge

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to make a SPA tic tac toe. Something is very off with my logic and I really need help. This is my first project and attempt at coding so please be gentle =)

```
const store = require('./../store')

const board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
// select user token
const newGame = []

const updateGame = function setToken(id) {
  if (id === 'x') {
    board.user = '"x"'
    board.opponent = '"o"'
  } else if (id === 'o') {
    board.user = '"o"'
    board.opponent = '"x"'
  }

  // set current player
  function setCurrentPlayer(player) {
    board.currentPlayer = 'player'
  }

  // mave move and switch player
  function makeMove(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      $(`#${i}`).text('')
    }
    // function to make move on the id passed
    if (board.currentPlayer === 'user') {
      // get element by id
      $('cell' + id).click(board.currentPlayer)
      // if current player selects a cell add id
      $('cell' + id).removeAttr('onClick')
      // if current player selects a cell on get game switch current Player
      onGetGame()
      setCurrentPlayer('opponent')
    } else if (board.currentPlayer === 'opponent') {
      $('cell' + id).click(board.user)
      $('cell' + id).removeAttr('onClick')
      onGetGame()
      setCurrentPlayer('user')
    }
    board.moves++
    // next player move ??
  }

  const checkforWin = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [6, 4, 2]
  ]
  // possible cells for winning
  function playerWin(id) {
    return board.checkforWin.some(function(cell) {
      return board.every(function(cell) {
        return board[cell] === id
      })
    })
  }

  // illegal move
  const illegalMove = function cellTaken(id) {
    if (id.cell.value.length === 0) {
      // if length of id is longer than 0
      return !
        //return false
        console.log('Space taken, try another space!')
    } else if (id.value.length === 1) {
      return true
      // if else return true
    }
    // tied game
    let tieGame = function(cellTaken) {
      return (board.every.(cellTaken))
      return true {
        console.log('DRAW!')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a linter error on this line. I'm attempting to use the .every method to have cellTaken function run and verify if the all the cells are filled to call a draw.

```
 return (board.every.(cellTaken))
```

Comment: Also Now I have a linter error on the line after

```
      return true {
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and good question (thanks for the [mcve])! Having said that, can you be a bit more specific about what aspect(s) of the logic are off? In other words, please post some sample runs of the program and illustrate exactly what about the behavior (expected input and output) is "off". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! So I really just don't funny understand how to make my game clickable. I understand I need click events, but my board isn't interactive at all. 

First I am trying to get the``` function setToken to responsive to a button I created in my html.  The button exists on my webpage has an X and O value stored inside, but there is no output on the console. I'm trying to start from the very beginning of my issues. Thanks so much for helping, sorry if this is too much.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the specific linter error, remove the . between every and the opening parenthesis.

```
return (board.every(cellTaken))
```